# how to fix this 'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public partial class allfiles : System.Web.UI.Page
{

received re = new received();
catgories cat = new catgories();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    { 
      DropDownList1.DataSource = cat.get_all_cat();
      DropDownList1.DataTextField = "اسم المستند";
      DropDownList1.DataValueField = "رقم المستند";
      DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
}
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
   // DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    TextBox10.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
    TextBox1.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[8].Text;
    TextBox2.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text;
    TextBox3.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[10].Text;
    TextBox11.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[11].Text;
    TextBox4.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[12].Text;
    TextBox5.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text;
    TextBox6.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text;


    DropDownList1.SelectedValue = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;



    TextBox8.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
    TextBox9.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;

}
```

When a row is selected then this error is displayed:

> 'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does
>   not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Comment: What does your data source look like?

Comment: Show your aspx source. What is the value of `GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text` at all?

Comment: Perhaps a ComboBox would be more suitable for this task as it allows to assign values not belonging to the list. There's an asp .Net implementation in  Ajax Control Toolkit .NET library.

Answer (score 1):

finely I found the solution 
this code

```
    DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text));
```

it works